# How to fix this Timer tick error in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, timer

I am using this code to receive data from an Internet address. However, when the timer ticks at first time the connection is OK and program works properly. **But in second time, an error is raised from this line**:

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

I want to know how to fix this problem.

Timer interval is 30 seconds.

Code:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost  
    /go/online.asp?prog=y&rln=" + Properties.Settings.Default.cos);

    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

    reader.Close();
    dataStream.Close();
    response.Close();
}
```

Error:
WebException was unhandled. 
The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

Comment: And I want to know what exception is thrown.

Comment: Can you post the error details?

Comment: @Bobby @Tom Squires Error:
WebException was unhandled. 
The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

Comment: @Bobby: what is internal error? how to fix this?

Comment: Is that your server application? If yes, it's broken. The problem is over there.

Answer (score 5):

Normally when I use a timer, I stop the timer before starting to process and then restart it when done processing. Try that and see if it works.

Comment: I suspect this may be related - if your timer event is firing again while the first one is already processing it can be troublesome.

Comment: I too agree with this solution

Comment: Do you mean timer1.Stop(); and timer1.Start(); ?

Comment: @Ajay @The Evil Greebo : If yes, the problem still persists.

Comment: Timer.Stop or Timer.Start should work, but you can also try Timer.Enabled = false and Timer.Enabled = true. Timer.Enabled = false will be used in the timer handler before you process any code. Timer.Enabled = true will be used in the same handler after you process your code.

Answer (score 2):

Mostly it happens because of the previous request is not completed while next timer ticks.
The first step is you should write try/catch block to handle the errors (or just to ignore). Also see what type of exceptions you are getting.

Alternatively you can use sockets to do the function recursively with some wait time.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can deactivate the timer in the timer event handler, and at the end reactive it.

Comment: Do you mean timer1.Stop(); and timer1.Start(); ? If yes, the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an `(500) Internal Server Error` then you'll have to check with the server to see what the error is.  Since it's localhost I assume you have access to the server.  That's where there error's going to be.